# Spreadsheet check IF-AND is not working when arrayformulaed

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have this formula

```
=ArrayFormula(if(AND(Input!A10:A=TRUE,Input!B10:B<>""),Input!C10:C & "_cn+" & Input!E10:E & "_ag+" & Input!G10:G & "_mu",""))
```

[image]

referring to these cells

[image]

I'm expecting the second row to contain text, but that's not the case.

[Spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ouCM7rCqvIo9xuiZhbAG1EI3pstQV2I6/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ArrayFormula(IF((Input!A10:A=TRUE)*(Input!B10:B<>""),
 Input!C10:C & "_cn+" & Input!E10:E & "_ag+" & Input!G10:G & "_mu", ))
```

Comment: Can you please explain why `*` over `AND(,)`?

Comment: @EladBenda sure. AND and OR are not supported under ARRAYFORMULA, therefore you need to use 0/1 logic to mimic it. multiplication instead of AND and addition instead of OR

Comment: same as `&` replaced by `+` under `ARRAYFORMULA` ? for concatenation?